# Using pandas, how do I turn one csv file column into list and then filter a different csv with the created list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, filter

Basically I have one csv file called 'Leads.csv' and it contains all the sales leads we already have. I want to turn this csv column 'Leads' into a list and then check a 'Report' csv to see if any of the leads are already in there and then filter it out.

Here's what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df_leads = pd.read_csv('Leads.csv')
leads_list = df_leads['Leads'].values.tolist()



df = pd.read_csv('Report.csv')
df = df.loc[(~df['Leads'].isin(leads_list))]
df.to_csv('Filtered Report.csv', index=False)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your code is partly redundant but correct. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```py
import pandas as pd 

df_leads = pd.read_csv('Leads.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('Report.csv')
set_filtered = set(df['Leads'])-(set(df_leads['Leads']))
df_filtered = df[df['Leads'].isin(set_filtered)]
```

**Note**: Sets, are significantly faster than lists for this operation.